# LyX - changing lists formatting

Tags: lyx, lists

In LyX, is there a way to change `Labeling` lists formatting of the Label? Instead of **bold**, I need it to be underlined.

Maybe I should create (if possible) a new kind of list?

Of less importance, I'd also like the label to end with a `:` . However, it can be easily typed manually, so it's only a nice-to-have feature.

Comment: You could do the underlying manually also, but it's always nice to make things automatic. Maybe you could use the description environment of the enumitem package and look at the options for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as far as I understand, is your question not related to LyX.

Depending on your document, there are several ways, to change the look of your list.

In case you use KOMA-Script, e.g. scrartcl, you could say

```
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont}
```

to prevent it from being set in bold.  Using `\underline` within the `\item` command, will do the trick.  Of course, you want it automatically, right?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}
\setkomafont{descriptionlabel}{\normalfont}
\begin{description}
\item[\underline{foo}] one
\item[bar] second
\item[baz] third
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

At least, this example produces:

[image]

Next trial:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\renewcommand*\descriptionlabel[1]{\hspace\labelsep\normalfont\underline{#1}\hfil}
\begin{document}
\begin{description}
\item[foo] one
\item[bar] second
\item[baz] third
\end{description}
\end{document}
```

Will produce

[image]

HTH

Jan